# Django raw SQL query trouble with format characters and string interpolation

Tags: mysql, django, union

In my Django app, I need to generate a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM player WHERE (myapp_player.sport_id = 4 AND (myapp_player.last_name LIKE 'smi%'))
UNION
SELECT * FROM player WHERE (myapp_player.sport_id = 4 AND (myapp_player.first_name LIKE 'smi%'));
```

I can't use Q objects to OR together the __istartswith filters because the query generated by the Django ORM does not use UNION and it runs at least 40 times slower than the UNION query above. For my application, this performance is unacceptable.

So I'm trying stuff like this:

```
Player.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM myapp_player WHERE (sport_id = %%s AND (last_name LIKE '%%s%')) UNION SELECT * FROM sports_player WHERE (sport_id = %%s AND (first_name LIKE '%%s%'))", (sport.id, qword, sport.id, qword))
```

I apologize for the long one-liner, but I wanted to avoid using a triple-quoted string while trying to debug this type of issue.

When I execute or repr this queryset object, I get exceptions like this:

```
*** ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 133
```

That's a single-quote in single quotes, not a triple-quote. If I get rid of the single-quotes around the LIKE clauses, then I get a similar exception about the close-paren ) character that follows the LIKE clause.

Apparently Django and MySQL disagree on the correct syntax for this query, but is there a syntax that will work for both?

Finally, I'm not sure that my %%s syntax for string interpolation is correct, either. The Django docs suggest that I should be able to use the regular %s syntax in the arguments for raw(), but several online resources suggest using %%s or ? as the placeholder for string interpolation in raw SQL.

My sincere thanks for just a little bit of clarity on this issue!

Comment: in your raw query, change `sport_id = %%s` to `sport_id = %s`. I doubt that would fix the issue, but it is invalid syntax

Comment: i believe you have to escape the `%` sign so each percentage sign you want in your query should be `first_name LIKE %%%s%%` additionally using LIKE queries is not going to scale, i would look into FULL TEXT indexing for your backend, or using one of the full text search engines

Comment: @jsarets Try this http://dpaste.com/hold/1211374/

Comment: I don't know why you're getting performance degradation when using OR. Have you tested the performance of you're union query against a query such as `SELECT * FROM player WHERE (myapp_player.sport_id = 4 AND ((myapp_player.last_name LIKE 'smi%') OR (myapp_player.first_name LIKE 'smi%')))`? Raw SQL really is supposed to be a feature of last resort. Also, have you considered adding index=True to the first_name and last_name columns? You'll see a pretty big performance win on this query if you do.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work like this:

```
qword = word + '%'
Player.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM myapp_player WHERE (sport_id = %s AND (last_name LIKE %s)) UNION SELECT * FROM myapp_player WHERE (sport_id = %s AND (first_name LIKE %s))", (sport.id, qword, sport.id, qword))
```

Besides the fact that %s seems to be the correct way to parameterize the raw query, the key here was to add the % wildcard to the LIKE clause before calling raw() and to exclude the single quotes from around the LIKE clause. Even though there are no quotes around the LIKE clause, quotes appear in the query ultimately sent to the MySQL sever.